# Why do my local temporary tables display as invalid object names in SQL Server 2008 but not in R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am moving some stored procedures from a database in SQL Server 2008 R2 to an identical database in SQL Server 2008 (not R2). One of them makes use of temporary tables. While the create script generated from the R2 database executed fine, the temporary tables and fields display as being invalid object names.

Here is a simple example...

[image]

So throughout this SP I have a bunch of squigly red underlines. None of the fields in the temp tables are listed in intellisense popups. This is not the case in the R2 database

The temporary table must be valid as the following works...

[image]

Is there anything I can do to make intellisense recognize the temp tables as valid object names?

Thanks,

John

Comment: As an aside to the question itself, a screenshot may work better to illustrate your first example.

Comment: Thanks. Forgot I could use screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in SQL Server 2008 pre-R2. Paraphrasing a bug report on [Microsoft's support site](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/483262/ssms-intellisense-doesnt-work-for-temporary-tables):

> **Description**
>
> Even after doing a refresh of Intellisense, it still underlines red
>   both the temp table names and fields that I have created.

This received the following response:

> **Posted by Microsoft on 02/07/2011 at 09:53**
>
> Thanks for your feedback. This issue was fixed in the SQL Server 2008 R2 release.

Unfortunately your answer seems to be that, other than update your destination database to R2, there is nothing you can do.

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure I can live with it now being reassured that it is just a cosmetic issue. I did several google searchees and came up empty handed. Not sure how you were able to find the answer at Microsoft Connect. I just tried to find the link you provided by searching and couldn't come up with any keywords that did the trick. Thanks again for the response.